# OpenGL: Light source that follows the camera?

Tags: opengl, light

Guys, how can this be. But in my previous projects, it wasn't. And I don't know how I attempt this effect. Tell me the truth, please.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what your problem is, or what you are asking about. Please try to make a more detailed description of your issue (code samples, diagram, something)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Section 18.050, How can I make my light move or not move and control the light position?](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm):

> First, you must understand how the
>   light position is transformed by
>   OpenGL.
>
> The light position is transformed by
>   the contents of the current top of the
>   ModelView matrix stack when you
>   specify the light position with a call
>   to `glLightfv( GL_LIGHTn, GL_POSITION, ... )`.
>   If you later change the ModelView
>   matrix, such as when the view changes
>   for the next frame, the light position
>   isn't automatically retransformed by
>   the new contents of the ModelView
>   matrix. If you want to update the
>   light’s position, you must again
>   specify the light position with a call
>   to `glLightfv( GL_LIGHTn, GL_POSITION, ... )`.
>
> ...
>
> - How can I make my light position stay fixed relative to my eye
>     position? How do I make a headlight?
>
> You need to specify your light in eye
>   coordinate space. To do so, set the
>   ModelView matrix to the identity, then
>   specify your light position. To make a
>   headlight (a light that appears to be
>   positioned at or near the eye and
>   shining along the line of sight), set
>   the ModelView to the identity, set the
>   light position at (or near) the
>   origin, and set the direction to the
>   negative Z axis.
>
> When a light’s position is fixed
>   relative to the eye, you don't need to
>   respecify the light position for every
>   frame. Typically, you specify it once
>   when your program initializes.

Comment: Umm, The FAQ's code example is incorrect.  There's no token `GL_LIGHT_POSITION` that was ever accepted by OpenGL.   Positioning a light should be set by calling `glLightfv( GL_LIGHT<n>, GL_POSITION, ... );`, where `<n>` represents the light number.  This answer has been edited to show the correct syntax.

Comment: @drewster: Fixed.